# Почему не работает transition?

Tags: css, transition

Вот тут не работает трансишн

```css
.balance{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.balance:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  background: red;
}

.balance:hover:before{
  transition: 0.8s;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, вы не указали на что должен действовать transition. Во-вторых, если имелся в виду top, то у него нет начального значения, а браузер не умеет делать transition от auto (значение по умолчанию для top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы применяете `transition` не к тому свойству.

У вас изначально, к псевдо-элементу `::before`, указано свойство `bottom: -50px;`, что указывает на то, что элемент "спрятан" под нижней границе родителя.
Осмелюсь предположить, что при наведение он должен плавно "показаться" снизу-вверх.
Если это так, то вы должны при наведение на родителя, "дать" псевдо-элементу `::before` свойство `bottom: 0`, а не как указанно у вас - `top: 0;`.

Вот пример:

```css
.balance{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.balance:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  background: red;
}

.balance:hover:before{
  transition: 0.8s;
  /*top: 0;*/
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="balance">Наведи на меня</div>
```

---

Так же предположу, что далее последует вопрос:

> почему после отведения курсора от элемента анимации нет

Отвечу:

Для этого свойство `transition` должно находится непосредственно в анимируемом элементе.

```
.balance::before {transition: 0.8s;}
```

Т.к. `.balance:hover::before` даёт понять браузеру, что анимация у псевдо-элемента должна появиться **только** при наведение на родитель.